# Qual è il significato di "pompare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio, pubblicato da Einaudi,  ho letto questo dialogo tra due partigiani, Ivan e Milton:

> – Non è questione di pazienza, ma di pelle. Quassú è
>   pericoloso. Le pattuglie.
>      – Non si azzardano fin quassú. Al massimo arrivano
>   alla strada ferrata.
>      – Da’ retta a me, Milton, **pompiamo**. L’asfalto non mi
>   piace.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "pompare" in questo brano. Ho cercato il significato del vocabolo in alcuni dizionari, ma le diverse accezioni non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa intende Ivan quando dice "pompiamo" a Milton?

Comment: Potresti fornire maggiori dettagli? Cosa facevano *lassù* Ivan e Milton? Erano a piedi?

Comment: @mrnld: Ivan e Milton vanno a piedi per la strada. Passano davanti a una villa che è su una piccola collina, "lassù" si riferisce a questo fatto. Si tratta della villa dove abitava, prima della guerra, Fulvia, ragazza amata da Milton che adesso è partita per Torino. Milton vuole soffermarsi per vistare la villa, ma questa idea non piace a Ivan: pensa che sia pericoloso.

Comment: @Charo, che accezioni hai trovato e in quale vocabolario? http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pompare/

Comment: @mie: Prima di tutto avevo consultato il Treccani, ma poi anche WordReference, il Sabatini Coletti e il De Mauro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pompare può significare "spingere forte sui pedali della bicicletta" (vedi [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pompare/)), dunque in questo contesto "camminare a passo rapido e serrato". Probabilmente "l’asfalto non mi piace" è anche una vera e propria allusione scherzosa al ciclismo: per il corridore partigiano è certo più adatto lo sterrato!

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @peterpoe, e grazie della risposta!

Answer (score 1):

Secondo il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI13/00845.jpg), che cita appunto il brano di Fenoglio che appare nella domanda, il significato di "pompare" nel contesto del testo è:

> Andarsene alla svelta, filarsela.

Cioè, Ivan esorta Milton di andarsene rapidamente dalla strada, che considera pericolosa a causa delle pattuglie.